# LVM or a ZPOOL?

Tags: lvm

Ubuntu 16.04 LTS - Server: What are the differences in performance between a ZFS (no RAIDZ) and a LVM - Of course by using the same HDDs. I used LVM for a long time until a fatal day I got a HDD failure (without the possibility of have a good backup for my  20TB). I need to take a decision (please: beside trying a good backup) between use LVM again or create a RAIDZ0 ZPOOL. What is the best option and why?. Thanks for your help.

Comment: what is more important: performance or data protection ? for me it is data protection and so I use zfs and btrfs - because both also using hash-sum to detect silent data corruption. there are tons of information on the Internet discussing possibilities of data corruption beside defect hardware

Comment: I tried and wanted to like lvm, but once I setup zfs I never looked back. Adding drives was easy and replacing a failed drive was easy too, didn't even lose any data. I'm using a raid 10 config. As far as I know you can't (easily) add drives to a raidz pool. And as far as efficiency raidz is going to be slower due to the parity.

Comment: After working for years with MDRaid and LVM, I got used to ZFS on BSD and then found out that ZFSonLinux is now ready for production (I could e.g. import ZFS disks from BSD to Linux without any problems). But I would not run the OS from ZFS disks - there are too many problems and drawbacks with grub. So I'ld suggest to have the OS and boot partition on some endemic filesystem (like ext4, maybe on mdraid1), and the data on a ZPOOL. And RAIDZn has of course some drawbacks with speed and extensability, but on the other hand has lots of advantages (snapshots, L2ARC, SLOG, and more).

Answer (score 0):

Luis,

First I have no info about RAIDZ0, but if follow RAID numbers this is stripping. In such case it does not matter if you use LVM with striped volumes of ZFS.
Will be better to reconsider your "RAID" strategy to use something like RAID5 or 6.

In sense of management LVM need more handwork, ZFS do automatically many things w/o need of operator intervention. But ZFS is "imported" from Solaris and IMHO its far far away from current ZFS because meanwhile Oracle develop a lot of good things in Solaris.

So my recommendation is to use LVM with proper RAID level